# Is there a way to force the sharepoint RSS viewer web part to get the latest 5 RSS feed items

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, web-part, xslt, rss

I added an RSS viewer web part to our sharepoint online site page, and i define this RSS feed url http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml + i define to get 5 items as follow:-

[image]

now i thought that i will get the latest 5 RSS items inside the RSS Viewer web part. but when i type the RSS feed url inside my browser, i found that the 5 RSS items inside our RSS viewer web part are not actually the latest 5.. so my question is if we can force the RSS viewer web part to get the latest items (in our case the latest 5 items)? as currently i am not sure which criteria the RSS viewer web part is actually using to get the 5 RSS items in our case (as seems they are not the latest 5 and are not the 5 items sorted alphabetically )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get latest 5 RSS items in RSS viewer webpart. But from RSS feeds source should return latest feeds in XML.

Comment: but seems this is not the case, as shown in my question.. i am not getting the latest 5 feeds... so if there a way to get around this?